# Lining a rectangular building square panels

Tags: proof-writing, induction, factorial

I've been working on this for what feels like a lifetime now and I'm just not getting anywhere with it. I'm wondering if someone would be able to explain how to solve it for me?

There is a rectangular building with the width 280m, length 336m, height 168m. Square panels are needed to cover the four walls, ceiling, and floor. The panels must be whole meters. What is the minimum number of equal sized square panels that are needed to line the building?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since the panels are square and you have to cover everything, you want the largest integer that divides 280, 336, and 168 simultaneously, i.e. you want the greatest common divisor.